# Update query for time that will save it to the database

Tags: mysql

I use the query:

```
UPDATE `times` SET `date` = 2012-04-04 WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id2` = 2;
```

It shows an update successful, but the time shows `000-00-00`.
any clue?

When i use phpMyadmin the filed will show what data I want to put in. After putting in the same information, the data changes. But how come sql doesn't?

Am I using the wrong data format for date?

Comment: The reason why it works in phpMyAdmin is because it automatically adds single-quotes to the input values

Comment: i added the '2012-04-04' and it seems to work in sql at least. But in my file ( view.php) in MVC still doesn't save it. At least I got the sql to work. I think it is because of my mvc now that has a problem. THanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose date with single quotes.

```
UPDATE times SET date = '2012-04-04' WHERE id=1 AND id2 =2;
```

Your previous statement was probably trying to update `date` to a numeric value of `2004` (`2012` minus `4` minus `4`).